# open mdb file in windows service

Tags: .net, windows, ms-access, service

When I debug on VS,I can access *mdb databases in my applcation (MS Access) without any troubles. In our old data exchange application, running as windows application it works also fine. Now we transformed the application to a windows service. In VS debugger, everything works fine too. But when installed as a service, it is not possible accessing a .mdb database. 
(Technology: OLEDB connection, coded in vb.net and c#)

I get always error messages as "file does not exist":
"*V:\DES_TCP\SW\TestMDB\DES_PdvData.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.* 
This is wrong, copying the path in an explorer can open the file.

Also already tried with a local .mdb file or running the service under another admin account as system. Does nothing change, access is not possible.

I did remember that already before 15 years we had troubles with that in context with IFix… The solution which the manufacturer proposed in this time was simply to start the IFix server driver not as a service...

It seems that it is restricted to access mdb files from a service.

Does somebody know something about such a restriction? And how it is possible to bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

By default services run under a restricted account.

You need to set the "run as" account in the services control panel to an account that has both "run as a service" permission and permissions to the directory you're trying to access.

**edit:**

It also needs to have access to the directory containing the Access DB driver DLLs, which IIRC, it doesn't, by default.

Comment: The mapped drive letter might also be problematic. A UNC path would be better.

Comment: @GordThompson: Good catch! The mapped drive is going to be a big problem because it doesn't exist for the service account. It can be created but is messy and AFAIK, not supported by MS.

Answer (score 0):

Jet engine works only with 32 Bit. Try to compile your windows service as x86!